# Android phone app is not installing the app in the connected android wear device

Tags: android, wear-os

I've created an android wear app and uploaded to the play store.When installed in phone it doesn't install the wear app automatically on the connected android device(In this case moto 360).I've triple checked the permissions ,application id and package name in both android wear and android phone projects.They are same. Since Google doesn't allow the feature of automatic installation of  the android wear app when the phone app is installed during development, uploading to the play store was the only option. Please help me in this regard.

Answer (score 0):

Run `adb logcat` and grep for your package name. This should show you potential issues with the installation.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the suggestion! I found the solution for the problem. I had added two extra permissions in andorid wear manifest.Since Google suggested that the permissions manifests of Phone app and wear app should be same, i had added the

"com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE"
                  and
    "com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION "

permissions in the android wear manifest as well. I removed them and updated the apk in the play store and installed the app again. When i did resync all the apps in android wear App of Google, my app appeared in the device.